# Google Cloud Storage free 50GB and pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage for my node.js.

I wonder after using the 50GB of free storage, the price will be *0.20$/gb? or starting from 0.2/gb?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to Storage Pricing and this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

The 50GB is just in example calculation which is posted there only to understand the pricing.

The price for data in Standard Class is 0.020$/GB (not 0.2$/GB - so 10 times less than in the question).

But this is only part of price.You have to be aware that total price of using storage consist of 4 elements:

- data
- network
- operation A (like insert etc.)
- operation B (like get etc.)

The prices in each area may be slightly different depending of chosen region.

All details of calculation you may find in mentioned earlier [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).